# What evidence exists supporting that Roddenberry thought of TOS as non-canon?

Tags: star-trek, canon, star-trek-tos, gene-roddenberry

I've seen [some people claiming](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17637/2565) (and [some repeating](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17924/2565) it) that Gene Roddenberry intended TOS to be excluded from Star Trek canon after making the first episodes of TNG.

I failed to find any evidence regarding The **Original** Series, supporting this claim. I think, in order to make a statement of such magnitude, there should be some quotes that clearly support this attitude.

---

I mean, it does make sense if we think about how much he hated making TOS compatible for the masses, but I always thought he managed to slip in his messages pretty well, while still disguising it as the western show he was supposed to deliver. So, announcing it was non-canon would also contradict the effort they took up to preserve continuity when creating TNG.

Comment: PIC or it didn't happen? :))) +1

Comment: To summarize the many references by those who knew him, regarding Roddenberry's view of canon: whatever came later in production order supersedes that which came earlier, whenever they conflict.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here's some quotes from Wikipedia's article on [Star Trek canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_canon#TV_series) (Bolding mine):

> People who worked with Roddenberry remember that he used to handle
>   canon not on a series-by-series basis nor an episode-by-episode basis,
>   but point by point. If he changed his mind on something, or if a fact
>   in one episode contradicted what he considered to be a more important
>   fact in another episode, he had no problem declaring that specific
>   point non-canon.
>
> > See, people can easily catch us, and say "well, wait a minute, in
> >     'Balance of Terror', they knew that the Romulans had a cloaking
> >     device, and then in 'The Enterprise Incident', they don't know
> >     anything about cloaking devices, but they're gonna steal this one
> >     because it's obviously just been developed, so how the hell do you
> >     explain that?" We can't. There are some things we just can't explain,
> >     especially when it comes from the third season. **So, yes, third season
> >     is canon up to the point of contradiction, or where it's just so
> >     bad... you know, we kind of cringe when people ask us, "well, what
> >     happened in 'Plato's Stepchildren', and 'And the Children Shall Lead',
> >     and 'Spock's Brain', and so on — it's like, please, he wasn't even
> >     producing it at that point.** But, generally, [canon is] the original
> >     series, not really the animated, the first movie to a certain extent,
> >     the rest of the films in certain aspects but not in all... **I know that
> >     it's very difficult to understand. It literally is point by point.** I
> >     sometimes do not know how he's going to answer a question when I go
> >     into his office, I really do not always know, and — and I know it
> >     better probably than anybody, what it is that Gene likes and doesn't
> >     like.[3]— Richard Arnold, 1991
> >
> > Another thing that makes canon a little confusing. Gene R. himself had
> >     a habit of decanonizing things. He didn't like the way the animated
> >     series turned out, so he proclaimed that it was not canon. He also
> >     didn't like a lot of the movies. So he didn't much consider them canon
> >     either. And – okay, I'm really going to scare you with this one –
> >     **after he got TNG going, he... well... he sort of decided that some of The
> >     Original Series wasn't canon either**. I had a discussion with
> >     him once, where I cited a couple things that were very clearly canon
> >     in The Original Series, and he told me he didn't think that way
> >     anymore, and that **he now thought of TNG as canon wherever there was
> >     conflict between the two**. He admitted it was revisionist thinking,
> >     but so be it.[4]— Paula Block, 2005

[CanonWars.com](http://www.canonwars.com/STCanon.html) has these same two quotes, as well as a bunch more information on all the later series and the movies.