# Is there any Star Trek material set after Nemesis?

Tags: star-trek, canon, star-trek-eu, star-trek-nemesis

I know of a fan-made series which I remember seeing advertised somewhere a year or two ago ([Star Trek: Phoenix](http://www.stphoenix.com/about.html)), and it got me thinking: is there any *canon* Star Trek material (I know - not the best term but you get what I mean) that is set *after* Nemesis?

I've seen [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31035/how-canon-is-the-star-trek-online-mmo) question already, so I know STO isn't counted as canon.

Note though that I *would* count a TV series, fan-made or not, if it covers the time period *after* Nemesis. There are no official works, so who's to say that's wrong (and often the fans have a better idea of what would actually happen than the official writers!)

Comment: The fan-made series I was thinking of is Star Trek: Phoenix.  This is the sort of thing that I'm talking about - productions set after Nemesis.

Comment: There is no Canon tng stuff after nemesis other than the reboot

Comment: It’s not particularly clear exactly what you’re asking here. You ask if there’s any canon post-Nemesis stuff, but say you’d accept canon or non-canon video productions, because there are no canon works at all?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- (Old) Spock's flashback scenes in [Star Trek](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_%28film%29) occur after Nemesis.

Depending how you define Canon:

- The comic book [Star Trek: Countdown](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek%3a_Countdown) occurs between Nemesis and the film above, and is [endorsed by Orci](http://trekmovie.com/2012/07/17/exclusive-orci-says-star-trek-tv-talks-getting-real-declares-movie-tie-in-comics-game-as-canon/).
- Starting with [Death in Winter](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Death_in_Winter), the books continued to explore the post-Nemesis world.

Comment: We've also seen time travel several centuries into the future in an "Enterprise" episode whose name I don't remember.

Comment: @KeithThompson That was the Enterprise-J in the episode [Azati Prime](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Azati_Prime_(episode)) (in an alternate timeline)

Comment: More specifically, Romulus's destruction is canon.

Comment: Enterprise is revealed in the final ep to be just a Holodeck game tho', so it's depictions of the far future can't be considered canon

Comment: @Gaius:   That is not the correct interpretation of that episode, although sometimes people suggest it because they think it disrespects the entire *Enterprise* series.   Just because events were replayed in the holodeck in the final *Enterprise* episode, does not suggest that in universe they didn't happen.   And especially, in no way does it suggest all the previous episodes 'only' occurred in the holodeck.   You could cite all kinds of evidence -- things occur in the series that clearly the 24th century holodeck wouldn't know about.

Answer (score 25):

The new 2020 series [Star Trek: Picard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Picard) starts after Picard's retirement as an admiral, and Data's death (in Nemesis) as a past fact is mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

I know you mention that STO isn't considered canon, but again it also depends how you define Canon but the Star Trek Online MMO continues the original universe following the events of countdown and Nemesis. It is separate from the books (especially the David Mack destiny Trilogies which conflict on several key races) and seems to follow the countdown timeline from what I can tell. You can read more about here:

http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Path_to_2409

And they did have several videos explaining the path to 2409 too, but those seem to have been taken down since the game changed companies.

I enjoy them as still relatively canon as they technically do not conflict with the new Trek (This continues the original timeline) and that they continue to get the original actors for speaking roles (Nimoy, does the introductions, Worf, Tuvok and even Sela have roles among others.)

Answer (score 3):

The Voyager finale (Endgame) is set partially in 2404, on/about the 10th anniversary of Voyager's "triumphant return to the Alpha quadrant after 23 years" and partially contemporaneous with TNG (the point to which Janeway returns to alter the timeline and accelerate Voyager's trip home).

At the time the question was asked, the answer (as far as on-screen licensed canon is concerned) would probably be the orphaned timeline depicted at the start of Endgame. Of course the passage of time has changed the answer with the debut of Star Trek: Picard.

There is another Voyager episode ("Timeless") set in a "future" in which Voyager is found crashed and frozen in ice 15 years after a failed experiment which put it there. The "future" is 2390, which also post-dates the events of "Nemesis" (2379). As in "Endgame", the future timeline as depicted becomes orphaned, in this case due to the efforts of "future" Chakotay and Kim to disrupt the experiment in a way that averts the crash.

Answer (score 3):

The new [Star Trek: Lower Decks](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Lower_Decks) is set in 2380 after Nemesis, as specified by stardate 57436.2 in the Captain's log in [episode 1](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Second_Contact_(episode)). [Nemesis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Nemesis) took place at stardate 56844.9.

Comment: Did they say it was canon?

Comment: This interview with the showrunner/creator says it's canon: https://comicbook.com/startrek/news/star-trek-lower-decks-canon-timeline/

Answer (score 3):

There is:

- Star Trek: Picard (Season 1 at least)
- Star Trek: Discovery (Season 3 and onward)
- Star Trek: Enterprise (Various points where Daniels takes Archer forward in time)
- Star Trek: Voyager

  - "End Game" Initially until Admiral Janeway travels back to Voyager's "present"
  - "Relativity" Various scenes on the starship Relativity in 29th century

That's the only occurrences that I'm aware of in Canon. I know that there's loads of books but I've no idea what's in them an which ones are considered canon