# Why has no new Star Trek show been set after Voyager?

Tags: star-trek

Has there been any **official** (from the studio or owners) reason why we haven't seen a new *Star Trek* show set after Voyager?

So far every new *Star Trek* show or movie is around The Original Series or close to an already established show:

- 2009 *Star Trek* reboot - The characters from The Original Series.
- *Star Trek: Discovery* - After Enterprise but before The Original Series. Season 2 will have Spock.
- The [JLP series](https://www.express.co.uk/showbiz/tv-radio/999530/Star-Trek-Jean-Luc-Picard-series-release-date-cast-trailer-plot-Patrick-Stewart-CBS) - Features obviously, Jean Luc Picard and takes place some time after Nemesis.

**Why haven't we seen a show set years after Voyager  and we follow a new crew *unrelated* to any series?**

--

I'm aware [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53546/is-there-any-star-trek-material-set-after-nemesis?rq=1) question asks for any material set after Nemesis, but I'm looking for an official studio reason **why** we haven't seen a **new** completely separate *Star Trek* series after Voyager and Nemesis.

Comment: The suggested duplicate asks why Discovery was a prequel series (and that's answered perfectly well, as something that started as a prequel at least appears to be what was pitched. It doesn't really answer why there's been no *next* Next Generation (and that's not really what was asked there). This question seems to be partly asking if the idea of a series set as far beyond the TNG era as TNG was beyond TOS would even be considered, or if that's been declared a no-go in advance by the studio.

Comment: @Paulie_D - What I'm suggesting is, a new show set lets say 50-100 years after Nemsis, a new ship, you can call it the Enterprise, but a new crew unrelated to the old one, new enemies. You can still call it Star Trek, and have the federation, but no characters from already established shows will pop-up. No need to have Spock show up, his story is done.

Comment: @RDFozz - Exactly, has there been an idea to have a show set far into the future, where TOS, TNG, DS9, Voyager and all the movies are essentially history, written in books. with a new crew?

Comment: @Paulie_D - That's exactly what I did. Do you see the question in my post? *Why haven't we seen a show set years after Voyager, all the TV shows and movies are now considered history within the timeline, and we follow a new crew unrelated to any series?*

Comment: @Paulie_D - Why is the post still considered duplicate?

Comment: "*Fuller sat with CBS executives to deliver his pitch. It wasn't just for a 'Trek' series but for multiple serialized anthology shows that would begin with the 'Discovery' prequel, journey through the eras of Captain James T. Kirk and Captain Jean-Luc Picard, **and then go beyond to a time in 'Trek' that's never been seen before**.
[...]
CBS countered with the plan of **creating a single serialized show and then seeing how it performed**.*"

Comment: Because *Voyager* sucked so hard that the entire galaxy was vacuumed into it and disappeared.

Comment: @nsutilities not sure...I've voted to reopen.

Comment: I truly doubt you'll find an answer to this question, but it's not a dupe.

Comment: Discovery is unrelated, and the new series will take place after nemesis (and therefore VOY). So you already got both, and another unrelated series would compete with Discovery, and another series after VOY would compete with Patrick Stewards work. But I doubt you'll find an "official" answer.

Comment: Enterprise had several storylines set in the distant future. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Enterprise#Temporal_Cold_War

Comment: might want to check out how Discovery S2 ended....

Comment: Lower Decks is set after Voyager and features an entirely new crew.

Answer (score 8):

Rick Berman and other producers for the franchise struggled to come up with compelling ideas for sufficiently advanced technology beyond what had already been shown in the previous shows, or at least ideas that would make for good television. In [this interview](https://youtu.be/7ILmc_a6Pyc?t=465) he mentions that the studio was interested in doing a show set in the 26th century, to which he responds "So, the spandex is a little tighter? The ships will go Warp 14?" I've also seen Berman quoted (though I don't have a source for this one) as saying "to go forward didn’t really offer us very much. To go forward meant spaceships that were a little sleeker and ships that were a little shinier, but there wasn’t that much to invent that we hadn’t invented already".

Comment: Here's a funny note about that then... Isn't discovery supposed to be in something like 10 years before the original series? And yet they give us this preposterous spore drive BS and over design everything. Had they just made discovery after voyager I think that detail alone would fit the needs of this question.

Comment: Then Berman lacks imagination.  How about transporters that can duplicate people or effectively make immortality and second childhoods a thing?  Mega transwarp engines capable of visiting alternate realities (or parallel worlds like the Abramsverse)?  Light-tracking computers that can recreate the past as it really happened?  The option of putting human brains into android bodies based on Data?  Berman doesn't want to explore later periods because he's not interested in that.  Period.

Comment: Even Voyager was set on the opposite side of the galaxy because Berman didn't want to keep doing TNG style stories.  that of course failed completely.  and the enterprise was set in the past to force them to stop doing tng stories.  again failed worse.

Comment: @TedMiller - In fairness if you watch the interview, Berman is talking about why he pushed for *Enterprise*, not why he never did another post-*Voyager* series...

Comment: And yet they had no problem doing Star Trek: Lower Decks and Star Trek: Picard and coming up with original ideas and stories. There's too much content floating around or before TOS. I think it's clear we want more content set after TNG/DS9/Voyager. They've only explored a fraction of the Milky Way and the shows were made in the 90s. There's plenty that can be done with improved graphics and more mature story writing.