# Who were the aliens in the "Star Trek: Enterprise" episode "Silent Enemy" (S01E11)?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

Grew up watching *Star Trek: TOS* reruns, then happily watched the newer series until life took over and I only ever caught a few episodes of *Star Trek: Enterprise*.

Now, with a bit more time on my hands, I started watching the series.  Watching S01E11, the aliens never seem to be named and I am just left wondering who they were.  Does anyone have any authoritative answer?

Answer (score 11):

According to [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Silent_Enemy_%28episode%29) they are never named in the series but return in a game (*Star Trek Online* expansion pack).  In the game they are called the Elachi.

Comment: Yeah, I came across that reference too when searching.  My issue with it is that video games are notorius for their inaccuracies and tend to be non-authoritative (since I haven't played many Star Trek games, maybe this is different with the Star Trek franchise?).  I was hoping someone would be able to dredge up something a bit more substantial.

Comment: @YLearn - STO is **not canon**: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31035/how-canon-is-the-star-trek-online-mmo

Comment: I agree that they bear a remarkable , yet creepy, resemblance to star trek online elachi.. my guess is just like the klingons lose their facial ridges later in the series so they can look like they do in tos: the elachi likewise have changed in appearance over the centuries too.