# Did any of the 79 TOS episodes contain plot points that conflicted with preexisting TOS canon?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, canon

I was recently watching a long running TV series (not SFF) where one of the character's father was dead, but later in the series, he was alive and came to visit.

With so many different writers, did any of the 79 TOS episodes contain plot points that conflicted with preexisting TOS canon? If so, which?

Comment: Well Kirk had a different middle initial in the first pilot on his tombstone.

Comment: @Oldcat It's the second pilot, actually. The first pilot featured Pike, not Kirk. (And wasn't broadcast, making the second pilot the first episode to be broadcast.)

Comment: [Answer to "What evidence exists supporting that Roddenberry thought of TOS as non-canon?"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/18003/2242) strongly related

Comment: [This guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phil_Farrand) wrote an entire book about errors in TOS. Admittedly, they are not all episode-spanning plot holes, but it should give you an idea …

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are numerous plot inconsistencies.

In ["The Squire of Gothos"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Squire_of_Gothos_(episode)) (first season), they hadn't yet decided how far in the future the story takes place. Trelane's planet is about 900 light-years from Earth. He's reproduced an Earth-like environment from roughly 200 years before the present (he mentions Alexander Hamilton). An officer mentions that it's as if he's been observing Earth through a telescope -- implying that the episode takes place about 700 years in the future, very roughly 2660.

In ["Tomorrow Is Yesterday"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tomorrow_is_Yesterday_(episode)), Kirk is at a US Air Force base in the 1960s. Lieutenant Colonel Fellini threatens to lock Kirk away for two hundred years. Kirk says, "That ought to be just about right" -- implying that the episode takes place about 2160 or so. (That episode was aired just 2 weeks after "The Squire of Gothos".)

In ["Obsession"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Obsession_(episode)), [Lieutenant Leslie](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Leslie) was killed by the cloud creature. He appeared, alive and well, in a number of later episodes, all the way to the end of the original series.

In ["The Conscience of the King"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Conscience_of_the_King_(episode)), Spock mentions that his father's planet was spared the dubious benefits of alcohol. McCoy replies, "Now I know why they were conquered". In the rest of the series, there's no indication that Vulcan was ever conquered; in fact, in ["The Immunity Syndrome"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Immunity_Syndrome_(episode)), Spock says that Vulcan has never been conquered in its collective memory.

And so on.

Comment: It only makes things worse, but 1960 + 200 = 2160, not 2260.

Comment: @BenHocking: Quite right, fixed. (2160 feels quite a bit closer now than it did when I first saw that episode.)

Comment: According to [EAS](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/biographies1.htm) and [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Galloway#Redshirt), Lt. Galloway was another similar case as Lt. Leslie.